# The .Net Concurrent BlockingCollection has a memory leak?

Tags: .net, memory-leaks, blockingcollection

I'm using a [Producer/Consumer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) with a `System.Collection.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<DataTable`> to retrieve data from a database (producer) and create a Lucene Index on the data (consumer).

The Producer grabs 10000 records at a time and adds the **set** to the `BlockingCollection<DataTable>`.  The consumer (which is a little bit slower) then grabs those 10000 and creates an index.

The blocking collection is bounded to 5 `<DataTable>` of 10000 rows each.

At first the program runs great but after its gets about 150000 rows in I noticed that my computers memory is maxed out and it slows to a crawl.

It seems that the BlockingCollection fails to set the underlying array slot to `null` after the item is taken.

Code:

```
    private static LuceneIndex index;
    private static BlockingCollection<DataTable> blockingCol;

    private static void Producer()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            //...get next 10000 rows
            DataTable data = GetNextSet();
            if(data.Row.Count > 0)
                blockingCol.Add(products);
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    private static void Consumer()
    {
        while (!BlockingCol.IsCompleted || BlockingCol.Count > 0)
        {
            DataTable data = blockingCol.Take();
            index.UpdateIndex(GetLuceneDocs(data));
        }
    }


 public static void Main(System.String[] args)
 {
            index = new LuceneIndex();
            blockingCol = new BlockingCollection<DataTable>(2);
            // Create the producer and consumer tasks.
            Task Prod = new Task(Producer);
            Task Con = new Task(Consumer);
            // Start the tasks.
            Con.Start();
            Prod.Start();
            // Wait for both to finish.
            try
            {
               Task.WaitAll(Con, Prod);
            }
            catch (AggregateException exc)
            {
               Console.WriteLine(exc);
            }
            finally
            {
               Con.Dispose();
               Prod.Dispose();
               blockingCol.Dispose();
             }
}
```

Can anyone confirm of reject this suspension? And is there any work around?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes I can confirm this. You aren't on .NET 4.5, are you? It is supposed to be fixed there (and your comments under this answer seem to confirm this).

Anyway, write yourself a wrapper around a `DataTable` and clear that wrapper when you are done with the table. That makes it eligible for GC. The wrapper will not be GC'ed early but it is tiny.

```
class Wrapper<T> { public T Item; }
```

Comment: I am on .net 4.5.  I'm actually using subsonic collection instead of datatable. I just included datatables in this example for simplicity.  I'll try your solution tho.

Comment: I guess it is not fixed then (probably I remembered). I have seen this problem myself, though.

Comment: Wrapper<DataTable> wrapper = BlockingCol.Take();
//do stuff
wrapper.Item = null;    This is what you mean right?

Comment: NVM the server is not running 4.5.  Must be the issue.  You solution worked perfectly tho. I'll be using it until I can upgrade the server. thanks